# Agency Fixed Rate RMBS Yield Decomposition

Tags: quantitative, bond-yields, yield, mbs, fixed

I'm trying to find the best way to decompose the yield on an index of fixed residential MBS securities and want to open up the question to the community. The goal is to look at this from a quantitative perspective. I have interest rate models, but no models strictly specific to mortgages. I also have all the index specific metrics I need, modified duration, option adjusted duration, average term to maturity, OAS (not my model but trusted), etc.

For return attribution, I've been able to fairly closely track total return with a duration matched Treasury total return and the total return on selling at the money swaps.

For a forward looking yield decomposition, I'm thinking of using an OAD matched Treasury yield, OAS, and a long term implied volatility to realized volatility adjustment.
$$ Y_{MBS} = Y_{durationMatchedUST} + OAS + Vol Adjustment$$
where
$$ VolAdjustment = \sum_{}^{1 year}Premiums_{vol= impliedVol} - \sum_{}^{1 year}Premiums_{vol= impliedVol*}$$

$impliedVol*$ is the implied volatility adjusted down by the long term difference in implied and realized volatility. The premise for $VolAdjustment$ is to capture additional expected yield from any volatility premium baked into the price of the MBS.

How else can I approach a decomposition? For the sake of this decomposition, we are assuming no ratings migration or default loss, so OAS should be premium for not knowing when payment will happen. We further adjust the premium for realized volatility. Any other adjustments needed?

Answer (score 1):

The traditional risk factor decomposition of a general MBS includes the following risk factors: Prepayment Risk, Interest-rate Risk (Realized Volatility), Basis Risk, Volatility Risk (Implied volatility), Financing/Leverage Risk, Liquidity Risk and Credit Risk. If the focus is on Agency MBS Pass-throughs then one usually assumes that Liquidity and Credit Risk are minimal. Financing/Leverage Risk is also typically neglected although this is much more questionable given the dramatic underperformance of MBS in situations where financing is hard to come by.

So much for the theory, in practice there has been too little published work on how one goes about estimating the excess return associated with these risk factors. One shining exception is: "Risk and Return in the Mortgage Market" by Amitabh Arora et al. In particular, take a look at the analysis in Section IV.